# Android : White screen when relaunch app

Tags: android, screen

I have a problem of white screen when I relaunch background app.

I click home button and then I click on app logo, my application resume and sometimes I have a white screen.

Do you know what's happening please?

Comment: Hmm, maybe something went wrong in onResume / onRestart?

Comment: it's on all activities, I don't think so.

Comment: Can you add Activity code?

Comment: Which activity ? the problem is in all activities and the code is different in all activities. I think it is in Manifest or my activity child

Comment: I put all methods in Application class app resume to a background thread still white screen appears for 1-2 seconds. So that is not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is the time that your application takes starting, before first activity is displayed.

If you extended the application class, you can look at the onCreate method, if there is much code here.

You can minimize the effects, setting the default window background to a color or drawable in a theme:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/mycolor</item>
```